# Setting read_ahead_kb on Kubernetes environment

Tags: linux, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

For setting read_ahead_kb, we need the device name. In Kubernetes environment how de we set read_ahead_kb for a statefulset pod requesting PV from remote storage. Any document which I can refer to set read_ahead_kb in Kubernetes environement

Answer (score 0):

as explained [here](https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra/issues/708#issuecomment-1710393140), you can use an init-container with root/privileged access to change the read_ahead value:

```yaml
        initContainers:
          - name: configure-read-ahead
            image: busybox
            # retrieve device id from volume mount
            command: [ "sh" , "-c", "blockdev --setra 256 $(mount | grep '/var/lib/cassandra' | cut -f1 -d' ')" ]
            securityContext:
              # required to access block device on /dev
              runAsUser: 0
              privileged: true
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra
                name: server-data
```

Note that `blockdev --setra` will expect a sector size value, which is usually twice the value in kb.